# Find php files with strings that have more than 50 characters

Tags: php, linux, grep, find

I am trying to run a command (find) for example that would allow me to find all the php files in which content there are strings with more than 50 characters.

I have a base that looks like this, but I fail what to write in the grep:

```
sudo find . -name '.*php' -exec fgrep -q '..' {} \; -print
```

I assume that a thing that is not a character is a whitespace. Basically I am trying to find PHP files that might have been compromisde with huge chunks of encoded64 strings.

Comment: What is not a character, whitespace?

Comment: Yes AbraCadaver, let's say I am trying to find words which have a length bigger than 50 characters.

Comment: So you are trying to find filenames containing words(white-space deliniated) longer than 50 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matches lines with 50 or more consecutive non space characters:

```
grep '[^ ]\{50,\}' *.php
```

Also, in Perl or PHP `preg_match()` I think this will match a base64 encoded string (any string that can be base64 decoded):

```
([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)
```