# Find all php files which first or second line have more than N characters

Tags: php, regex, grep, find

How would I go on writting a program that would look for all my php files which first or second line contain more than N characters? I would like to show the name of the file and the content of the line

I am able to go file by file with this:

```
    <html><head><title>Find String</title></head><body>
    <?php
    find_files('.');
    function find_files($seed) {
        if(! is_dir($seed)) return false;
        $files = array();
        $dirs = array($seed);
        while(NULL !== ($dir = array_pop($dirs)))
        {
            if($dh = opendir($dir))
            {
                while( false !== ($file = readdir($dh)))
                {
                    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
                    $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
                    if(is_dir($path)) { $dirs[] = $path; }
                    else { if(preg_match('/^.*\.(php[\d]?)$/i', $path)) { check_files($path); }}
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
    }

    function check_files($this_file){

        if(!($content = file_get_contents($this_file)))
        { echo("<p>Could not check $this_file You should check the contents manually!</p>\n"); }
        else
        {
            // What to do here??
        }
        unset($content);
    }
    ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: is this is a real world requirement? :-)

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean? I have had injected code in my php files, and usually the content is injected in first or second line...

Comment: @HommerSmith you don't know what else has been injected or altered, nor where. The only sensible thing to do is delete everything and restore from a clean backup. After that, patch your software to close the hole through which the attack came.

Comment: if thats the problem this is not the way to deal with it, restore from back up. you cant be sure you will get all injected code using this method.

Comment: I know I need to restore from a backup. I am blaming the guys from the server who are saying 'there is no backups'. Thanks for the suggestions though guys.

Comment: Please add `linux` and `bash` as tags, I'm pretty sure there is a command for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the comments to restore from backup and also identify and eliminate the vulnerability.  But to answer the question:

```
foreach(glob('path/*.php') as $file) {
    $lines = file($file);

    if(strlen($lines[0]) > $N) {
        echo "$file : line 1 : {$line[0]}\n";
    }
    elseif(strlen($lines[1]) > $N) {
        echo "$file : line 2 : {$line[1]}\n";
    }
}
```

There is a similar question from yesterday: [Find php files with strings that have more than 50 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206706/find-php-files-with-strings-that-have-more-than-50-characters/22210870#22210870) with the same issue.

Comment: What about a linux script which would do that in a sexier way?
I don't know yet, but I'm pretty sure "find" could do something like that.

Comment: Yes, check the link to the OP's other question.